# How do I project models into viewmodels in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Given the following classes:

```
public class Neighborhood
{
    public IEnumerable<House> Houses { get; set; }
}

public class House
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public IEnumerable<Furniture> Furniture { get; set; }
}
```

I want views that look something like this:

```
<!-- Want DataContext to be a NeighborhoodViewModel, not a Neighborhood -->
<NeighborhoodView>
    <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Houses}/>
    <Button Content="Add House"/>
    <Button Content="Remove House"/>
</NeighborhoodView>

<!-- Want DataContext to be a HouseViewModel, not a House-->
<HouseView>
    <TextBox Text={Binding Address}/> 
    <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Rooms}/>
    <Button Content="Add Room"/>
    <Button Content="Remove Room"/>
</HouseView>

<!-- Want DataContext to be a RoomViewModel, not a Room -->
<RoomView>
    <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Furniture}/>
    <Button Content="Add Furniture"/>
    <Button Content="Remove Furniture"/>
</RoomView>
```

However, I don't want NeighborhoodViewModel to contain HouseViewModels. Rather, it should be like:

```
public class NeighborhoodViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Room> Rooms { get; }
    public ICommand AddHouseCommand { get; }
    public ICommand RemoveHouseCommand { get; }
}
```

**How can I declare bindings to models in XAML, but have the bindings be transformed into viewmodels?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two general ways you can create this type of effect. The first way is to create a static view and put a DataContext behind each view. This is not MVVM where the views are generated by the ViewModel but this will get your bindings to work.  This is an example of view.

```
<Grid>
    <HouseView x:Name="myHouse">

    </HouseView>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind you can get access to your HouseView and set the data context

```
public MainWindow()
{
    myHouse.DataContext = new MyHouseViewModel();
}
```

This will get your bindings to work for each one of these controls.

I will say that this is not the best practice of WPF and it is certainly not a way to develop large projects. However this will do for quick and dirty coding in my opinion. You can find out more on how to do proper MVVM style of coding [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

Comment: So would you suggest having NeighborhoodViewModel contains a collection of HouseViewModel? In that case, where will HouseViewModels be created when Add House is clicked? If Add House is a command on NeighborhoodViewModel, then NeighborhoodViewModel has to either construct a HouseViewModel, delegate the construction to a factory, or take AddHouseCommand as a dependency. Does this sound right? If so, what's your preferred approach?

Comment: In general, I would have the neighborhoodViewModel  have all of the HouseViewModels in a collection. Then each houseViewModels would have all of the RoomsViewModels in a Collection. This way what you need to do is to create a DataTemplates that create the view. The add houseCommand would be located in the neighborhoodViewModel since that is where you will be adding the house. The neighborhoodViewModel would call your house factory and then add it to the collection once the factory returns the built house. This way the parent object knows its children by default since it creates it.